# RavenDB - Document references

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I am RavenDB noob trying trying to understand how does RavenDB knows to link a document to another?

It appears to me that it scans every property of the document and if the proprety value matches a documentId, it shows that a reference in the studio, even though I didn't really try to make it a reference.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks,

[image: RavenDB Studio Document References]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juma,
This is merely a UI feature, it is based on looking for conventions, and it has no operational impact.